# Table name with special character in the end

Tags: oracle

I have a table in database(oracle sql) which somehow contains one special character at the end which I dont know.I am trying to get that special character from its entry in table `tab`.

```
SQL> SELECT tname from tab where tname='OPERATION';

no rows selected

SQL> SELECT tname from tab where tname like 'OPERATION%';

TNAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
OPERATION

SQL> SELECT length('OPERATION') from tab where tname like 'OPERATION%';

LENGTH('OPERATION')
------------------------
                       9

SQL> SELECT length(tname) from tab where tname like 'OPERATION%';

LENGTH(TNAME)
-------------
           10
```

So , there is one special character after char `N` in string `OPERATION` .
I tried getting the last character using `substr` but that did not help.

How can I find this special charater ( or even `ascii` value of this character ) ?

And how can I run `select` on the data in this table ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try the `dump` function to get the actual byte values stored. For example, I just created a table `"OOUPS "`, with a space at the end.

```
> select table_name, dump(table_name) from user_tables;
...
OOUPS   Typ=1 Len=6: 79,79,85,80,83,32
...
```

You can see 32 (0x20 hex) as the last char - that's an ASCII space.

Once you've found what the extra character is, you can query the table using double quotes around the name. This is case-sensitive, so make sure you match that too. e.g.:

```
create table "OOUPS " (a int);
insert into "OOUPS " (a) values (42);
commit;
select * from "OOUPS ";
```

And of course:

```
alter table "OOUPS " rename to more_sane_name;
```

If you can't type the strange character easily, simplest way would be to create an SQL script, or pipe the exact character sequence to SQL*Plus:

```
OOUPS   Typ=1 Len=6: 79,79,85,80,83,13
```

```
$ echo -e 'alter table "OOUPS\r" rename to saner_name;\nexit;' | sqlplus user/pass
...
Table altered.
```